# jqGrid gridComplete error reloadGrid on loadcomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I was doing some tests and i want to move to another on loadlComplete in, but the grid dont reload.

If i exectue this statement on firebug the grid reload: jQuery("#participations").jqGrid('setGridParam',{page:2}).trigger("reloadGrid");

Why this dont work on loadcomplete?

```
         jQuery("#participations").jqGrid({url:'bd/getParticipations_pageable.php',
        datatype: "json",
        postData:{contestId:contestId},
        width:920,
        height: "auto",
        scrollOffset:0,
        colNames:['','Participa&ccedil;&atilde;o', 'Email','Nome','Telem&oacute;vel'],
        colModel:[
             {name:'id',index:'id', width:210, sorttype:'int', hidden:false, sortable:false},
             {name:'participation',index:'participation',sortable:false},
             {name:'email',index:'email',width:35,sortable:false},
             {name:'name',index:'name',width:35,sortable:false},
             {name:'moreInfoBtn',index:'moreInfoBtn', width:43,sortable:false}

            ],
        rowNum:15,
        hidegrid: false,
        pager: '#participationsPager',
        sortname: 'id', 
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"Participa&ccedil;&otilde;es",
            gridComplete: function(){


             var ids = jQuery("#participations").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
             var rows = jQuery("#participations").jqGrid('getRowData');

             var mydata = $("#participations").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
            jQuery("#participations").jqGrid('setGridParam',{page:2}).trigger("reloadGrid");


        }
        ,loadComplete:function(){




        },
}).navGrid("#participationsPager",{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false});
```

Comment: Both `loadComplete` and `gridComplete` will be called after every server request (this is a simplification as their fire at different stages) so if after every request you are trying to reload grid once again I would expect an infinite loop.

Comment: So, what's the alternative to it?